# problema con mandar una variable en vb "Index out of limit"

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando con 3 proyectos, Portal, RenegNetBLL y WsDeclas y tengo que pasar una variable desde el portal, por RenegBLL hasta WsDeclas que finalmente conecta con una base de datos en Oracle.

Cada aplicación tiene una referencia hacia el otro proyecto para usarse, por ejemplo el portal tiene un Reference hacia RenegNetBLL y a su vez este proyecto tiene un Web Reference hacia WsDeclas.

Internamente yo ya declaré la variable que necesito ir pasando en las funciones hasta llegar a WsDeclas pero me salta un error en WsDeclas:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
> array.    at WsDeclas.Negocio.OracleBL.TraeDeudaPorRut(String rut,
> DateTime fechaProy, String oferta, String honorario) in
> C:\Users\smiranda.apiux\Desktop\RESPALDO FIRES\PlataformaOperacional
> WSDECLA\ws\WsDeclas\Negocio\OracleBL.cs:line 495    at
> WsDeclas.WsDeclas.TraeDeudaPorRut(String rut, DateTime fechaProy,
> String oferta, String honorario) in
> C:\Users\smiranda.apiux\Desktop\RESPALDO FIRES\PlataformaOperacional
> WSDECLA\ws\WsDeclas\wsDeclas.asmx.cs:line 1991

El orden es **RenegNetBLL** -> **wsDeclas.asmx.cs** llama al **OracleBL.cs**

El código en RenegNetBLL es:

```
Public Function TraeDeudaPorRut(ByVal rutCliente As String, ByVal fechaProy As DateTime, ByVal oferta As String, ByVal honorario As String
                                    )

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = Ws_Declas.TraeDeudaPorRut(rutCliente, fechaProy, oferta, honorario)
        Return dt

    End Function
```

el código en **wsDecas.asmx.cs** es:

```
Public Function TraeDeudaPorRut(ByVal rutCliente As String, ByVal fechaProy As DateTime, ByVal oferta As String, ByVal honorario As String
                                    )

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = Ws_Declas.TraeDeudaPorRut(rutCliente, fechaProy, oferta, honorario)
        Return dt

End Function
```

El codigo en WsDecla.TraeDeudaPorRut es:

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataTable TraeDeudaPorRut(string rut, DateTime fechaProy, string oferta, string honorario) //, srting honorario
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt = OracleBL.TraeDeudaPorRut(rut, fechaProy, oferta, honorario); //, honorario

            return dt;
        }
```

Y el de OracleBL.cs es:

```
    public static DataTable TraeDeudaPorRut(string rut, DateTime fechaProy, string oferta, string honorario)
    {
        List<string> TO = new List<string>() {"09278","09279","00471","00670","09227","09228"};

        SqlOraDB conn = new SqlOraDB();
        string package = "PK_SCF_RENEGOCIACION_ONLINE.Sp_Scf_TraeDeudaPorRut";

        OracleParameter[] parametros = new OracleParameter[4];

        parametros[0] = new OracleParameter("pRutDeudor", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        parametros[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametros[0].Value = rut;

        parametros[1] = new OracleParameter("fechaProyec", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        parametros[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametros[1].Value = fechaProy.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        parametros[2] = new OracleParameter("pOferta", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        parametros[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametros[2].Value = oferta;

        parametros[3] = new OracleParameter("pHonorario", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        parametros[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parametros[3].Value = honorario;

        parametros[4] = new OracleParameter("Io_Cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        parametros[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        DataTable dat = conn.ExecutePackageWithParameters(package, parametros, SqlOraDB.enumConn.OracleConn).Tables[0];

        var rezint = (from row in dat.AsEnumerable()
                      where TO.Contains(row.Field<string>("TOO"))
                      select row).ToList().Count;

        return dat;

    }
```

El procedimiento en Oracle lo definí como:

```
 Procedure Sp_Scf_TraeDeudaPorRut(pRutDeudor Varchar2,
                                     fechaProyec Varchar2,
                                     pOferta Varchar2,
                                     pHonorario Varchar2,
                                     Io_Cursor  Out Mycursor);
```

Cada proyecto lo compilé y lo guardé en la ruta que le corresponde dentro de mi servidor, actualicé las referencias pero al probar, el webservice WsDeclas con su funcion TraeDedudaPorRut me arroja ese error.

¿Estoy haciendo o declarando mal alguna llamada?

Si se necesita más información me avisan y la pongo pero creo que con esto se entiende.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Diría que tienes mal definido el array de parametros. Prueba con `OracleParameter[] parametros = new OracleParameter[5];` dado que realmente estas metiendo 5 parametros y no 4

Comment: Creo que tienes razón, me centré en pasar la variable y no me fijé en esa, lo voy a programar y comento, muchas gracias